# Is Selenium a security vulnerability?

Tags: selenium, security, automation

I'm learning Selenium but I am concerned that the Webdriver (Chromedriver.exe, Geckodriver.exe) seems to open a port for communication functioning as a proxy between the selenium code and the browser. I don't want to expose myself to any vulnerabilities and would prefer some form of direct browser communication.  I've viewed several solutions, but selenium just seems to be the reigning champion.

It appears that some form of what I am looking for was present with PhantomJS, but that seems to be no longer supported.  This leaves me two options:

-Find a browser that selenium can communicate directly with without the aid of Webdriver.

-Find a way to completely restrict that port that it seems to open up so it does not allow connections from anybody on the network and no one can connect to my local machine.

Any suggestions folks?

Comment: [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) is a modern alternative for selenium, though I don't know whether it alleviates any of your security concerns.

Comment: Yeah, I've used it and it's great.  It apparently uses Chrome's remote debugging port which is another use of the network that I'd rather it not do.  Cypress seems to indicate that it does direct browser interaction but it fails me in other ways like creating dynamic ways to prompt for user input.

Thank you for the response.